# Component binding cause :Duplicate component ID found in the view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am using below code

```
 <rich:tree id="ed-treeNetwrk000" toggleType="ajax" binding="# {bean.treeBinding}" toggleListener="#{bean.processTreeToggle}"
 selectionType="ajax" var="item3"
 selectionChangeListener="#{bean.processTreeSelectionChange}"
 rendered="#{!anotherBean.isEditValue}"
 reRender="selectedNode"
 render="panel1,panel2,panel3">
 <rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor id="ed-networkList00"
 roots="#{bean.networkRoot}"
 nodes="#{item3.value}">
 <rich:treeNode id="ed-networkName"
 iconCollapsed="/resources/images/collapse.png"
 iconExpanded="/resources/images/expand.png"> #{item3.value.name}
 <rich:contextMenu id="ed-contextMenuNetwork5" target="ed-networkName"  direction="auto"  attached="true" targetSelector=".rootNetwork">
 <rich:menuItem id="ed-createEquipNw" label="Add in Collection" action="#{bean.addInCollectionEdit}">
 <f:param name="action" value="delete" />
 </rich:menuItem>
 </rich:contextMenu>
 </rich:treeNode>
 </rich:treeModelAdaptor>
 </rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor>
 </rich:tree>
```

When first time page rendered it will rendered fine but again if i will try to open the same page it will fail with error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID has already been found
>   in the view

Note - My Bean is session scoped .

Comment: Post your complete rich:tree

Comment: Please, please, please learn to use google. Posting the error in combination with 'jsf' and 'stackoverflow' is always something to try... More than one post about this in stackoverflow and I know for sure the answer to your question is there. Hint: it has to do with the scope! https://www.google.com/search?q=JSF+binding+java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+Component+ID+has+already+been+found+in+the+view